# Javascript bookmarklet no change css?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

When I go to Google and try this bookmarklet, it doesn't work? Any help please?

```
javascript:void(document.getElementById('lga').style.display == 'none')
```

`lga` is the logo id which I found by inspecting the element. Thanks!

Comment: Why the down votes for his poor English?

Comment: @RutwickGangurde What evidence do you have that the down votes are related to his English? Perhaps they are related to the fact his question is extremely mundane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `==` which is a comparison operator. You want just a single `=` which will set the value of `style.display` to `none`.

```
javascript:void(document.getElementById('lga').style.display = 'none')
```

Comment: thank you, it work now.  is there any way to add title to my bookmarklet in the javascirpt?